# How to downgrade python 3.7 to 3.6?

Tags: python, archlinux

After updating my system via pacman (arch linux 4.18) most of the python scripts aren't working anymore (errors about missing modules, pipenv errors, vim plugins errors).

How can I revert python to 3.6?

Google didn't offer any satisfying solutions on that issue

Comment: i have same problem please tell me the solution if you fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall your current installation with:

```
$ pacman -Rdd python
```

and then install this package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python36/

Comment: Thanks  @ruohola, alas this throws a vast list of `..removing breaks dependency 'python'`.

Comment: DO NOT UNINSTALL PYTHON IF YOU ARE USING INTERFACE

Answer (score 0):

Use `conda search python` to select the version of python you want to downgrade to then use something like `conda install python=3.6.0` if you want to downgrade to 3.6.0

Comment: Where does OP say anything about him using `conda`?

Answer (score -4):

Try this in your terminal/cmd:

```
$ brew unlink python
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/e128fa1bce3377de32cbf11bd8e46f7334dfd7a6/Formula/python.rb
$ brew switch python 3.6.5
```

Comment: Where does OP say anything about him using Homebrew?

Comment: You copied this answer straight from here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979504/9835872